# Code coverage tool for hack language

Tags: code-coverage, hacklang

Is there a code coverage tool for Hack language (on hhvm)?

This question is not about code coverage on PHP source code running on hhvm (which is possible using PHPUnit for example), but to generate code coverage of source code written in hack language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current version of PHPUnit(4.4,4.5,4.6) doesn't generate coverage and it fails with this error.

```
$php phpunit-alpha.phar -coverage-html=cover t/
PHPUnit alpha-2015-01-09 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors. 

PHPUnit alpha-2015-01-09 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
Fatal error: Class undefined: PHP_Token_TYPELIST_LT in phar://phpunit-alpha-2015-01-09.phar/php-token-stream/Token/Stream.php on line 185
```

<strike>I do agree that with Ira that code coverage is using XDEBUG. However for some reason PHPUnit has not decided to have HackLang code coverage.</strike>

**First Update:**

It is because Hacklang has more registered commands(like shape, type) and more structures(lambda), which php-token-stream is not able to recognize them.

The fix is quite simple though, you can create the class that is not defined and extend it from PHP_Token. For instance for my project I had to create these classes:

```
class PHP_Token_TYPELIST_LT extends PHP_Token {}
class PHP_Token_TYPELIST_GT extends PHP_Token {}
class PHP_Token_TYPE extends PHP_Token {}
class PHP_Token_SHAPE extends PHP_Token {}
class PHP_Token_LAMBDA_OP extends PHP_Token {}
class PHP_Token_LAMBDA_CP extends PHP_Token {}
class PHP_Token_LAMBDA_ARROW extends PHP_Token {}
```

**Second Update:**

PHPUnit is using [CodeCoverage](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage) to detect the executed line and in that project, on HHVM it's using [fb_get_code_coverage](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage/blob/master/src/CodeCoverage/Driver/HHVM.php#L50)

Answer (score 1):

The internal representation of Hack code is *very* similar to that of PHP. Depending on how exactly existing code coverage libraries do their checking, it's possible that they'll just work. Have you tried using PHPUnit to write test cases over Hack code? Their coverage, for example, might just work!

Comment: Yes we tried PHPUnit. It works well for running tests (hhvm runs Hack no different than PHP). But Coverage failed with errors while parsing the Hack source file.

Answer (score 1):

While it may be useful for OP to *write* testing code in PHPUnit, most of the PHP test coverage tools (including PHPUnit as I understand it) use XDEBUG to collect their test coverage data.  I'm not familiar with the Hack implementation but I understand it has nothing to do with Zend... so the likelyhood it contains XDEBUG seems kind of remote.  (Maybe Hack copied XDEBUG exactly?) If XDEBUG is not available under Hack, those XDEBUG-based coverage tools literally cannot collect the data they need.

To the extent that Hack is a identical to PHP, our [PHP Test Coverage Tool](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage/PHPTestCoverage.html) will probably work directly.  It instruments *source* code, and so is not dependent in any way on the existence of XDEBUG.  I suspect PHPUnit could easily be adapted.

(If Hack is not exactly the same, the test coverage tool could be revised to handle the changed syntax pretty easily, since it is based on a general purpose program transformation system).

Comment: HHVM supports a large portion of xdebug as of version 3.4 I think, fairly recently. It should work on Hack code just as well as it does on PHP, but HHVM only supports common bits of xdebug used for IDE debuggers, so it may or may not support the bits that PHPUnit needs for coverage data.